# HTML5 Canvas in Chrome suddenly stopped working. Why?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I've been working on this site for a while, and recently began working to replace my old animated Flash menu with a new animated HTML5 menu. So far all I have is a few colored orbs that wander around randomly. I haven't had a chance to work on it for a couple weeks, but when I got on today I noticed that my navigation has disappeared! When I refresh the page (in Chrome) the entire Canvas area turns black. This is only happening in Chrome (works fine in Firefox & Safari), and I haven't made any changes to anything since it was working a couple weeks ago.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on here?

Edit:
Totally forgot to include the url. It's   http://www.tylergerard.com
Also, there is a lot of javascript going on that is probably very buggy. I appreciate any feedback on that, but this post is in regards to the Canvas specific problems.

Comment: Works for me in `Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m`

Comment: That is strange. I have the exact same version of Chrome. I cleared my cache and all other data on a hunch but it didn't help.

Comment: am I supposed to see circles moving around? If so I definitely can. As any wise IT support desk would tell you, restart your computer. lol (sarcasm)

Comment: works for me in Chrome !

Comment: I've tested it on the EXACT same version of Chrome on a friends MacBook which is identical to mine. It seems to be happening only on MY laptop, and ONLY in Chrome. I've restarted, reinstalled Chrome, done everything I can think of. No luck. I'm going mad!

Comment: Well it works in Incognito Mode. Still blank in regular mode even after clearing ALL browsing data and re-installing Chrome. This is one heck of a brain-teaser.